# Integers below 1

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to make an integer that is below 1? Like 0.5?

Because when I am using 0.5, it does not work.

Any solutions?

My Code:

```
BallTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(ballMove) userInfo:nil repeats:(YES)];

-(void)ballMove {    
    redBall.center = CGPointMake(redBall.center.x - ballSide, redBall.center.y - ballGravity);    
}

ballCheck = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(ballCheck) userInfo:nil repeats:(YES)];

-(void)ballCheck {
    ballGravity = ballGravity - 0.5;        
    if (redBall.center.y >= 280) {
        ballGravity = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Last time I attended a math class, 0.5 wasn't considered an integer. Also, this has **nothing** to do with Xcode at all.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about elementary maths.

Comment: Did you want a [float(ing) point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)?

Comment: @yomaxyo99 I was 15 when I started learning Objective-C. Yet I didn't have to ask questions like this because I had the ability to use Google. It wouldn't hurt you either.

Comment: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/primitives.html

Comment: @yomaxyo99, Though your age is irrelevant in this case, please do not be discouraged by the reactions.  However, I highly recommend reading an introduction to C or Objective-C (or at least doing a basic Google or SO search) before asking elementary questions.

Comment: I am not being discouraged. I will thank you for your help, but i have been banned from this site because this topic has -4 votes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An integer, by definition, is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. Integers can also be 0 or negative (i.e. -1, -2, -3, etc). Numbers with decimal places are not integers. What you suggest would require a `float`, meaning it has a floating decimal. Alternatively, you could use a `double`, which allows for much larger numbers (and more decimal places).

Comment: Also `-1` and `0` are valid (signed) integers.

Comment: Woops, I meant to add those in before I officially posted the answer. I'll add them now.